# receiveMessages method with maxWaitTime not working as expected

Tags: java, azure, azureservicebus, servicebus, messagebroker

I am working on azure service bus and using **ServiceBusReceiverClient.receiveMessages(int maxMessages, Duration maxWaitTime)** method to receive the message from the service bus, **my use case is to receive batch of messages in specific amount of time**. But this is not working as expected **it is not waiting for duration maxWaitTime**, it start the processing of the message as soon as one message is received.

Below is code snippet:

```
 ServiceBusReceiverClient receiver = new ServiceBusClientBuilder()
        .connectionString(connectionString)
        .receiver()
        .maxAutoLockRenewDuration(Duration.ofMinutes(1))
        .queueName("<<queue-name>>")
        .buildClient();
    while (true) {
        
        Iterator<ServiceBusReceivedMessage> iterator =  receiver.receiveMessages(10, Duration.ofMinutes(2)).iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            ServiceBusReceivedMessage serviceBusReceivedMessage = (ServiceBusReceivedMessage) iterator.next();
            System.out.println("received message is  ->"+serviceBusReceivedMessage.getBody());
            
        }
        
    }
```

**it should wait for at least two minute to receive 10 messages but, it start processing with only one message within seconds.**

Comment: This is not what the `maxWaitTime` is supposed to do. the `maxWaitTime` is the maximum time the receiver is waiting for a message before timing out.

Answer (score 0):

@Abhijit,

The `MaxWaitTime` is Client wait time from the service bus before the message gets delivered to the client. It skips the specific message when it exceeds wait time.

[image]

There one  approach I can think of  that can help you :

- Check for Active messages count and if it is more than 10. Then
  proceed with reading the messages.

  [Reference](http://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.management.servicebus.messagecountdetails.activemessagecount?view=azure-java-stable#com_microsoft_azure_management_servicebus_MessageCountDetails_activeMessageCount__)

  **Note** : You may need Service Bus admin client for this.
- If the count of messages is not reached 10 by say 5 minutes - then go
  ahead & read the available messages.